# Exporting data using msgbox BeforeClose only if the workbook the data is being exported to is closed

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to export data to another workbook. I have added a msgbox before close asking if I'm ready to export the data. When I select yes the data exports. The issue I'm having is that the workbook the data exports to is regularly being used. I want to add a feature to my code that will notify the user the data won't be exported as the workbook is open elsewhere. If the workbook is closed I would like the data to export.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Output As String

Output = MsgBox("Are you ready to export the data?", vbYesNo, "Data Export")

If Output = vbYes Then

'Summary Page (APD+MTC)

'APD Premium

Worksheets("SEC 1 (APD)").Range("AJ" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy

Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\US Div\Accounts\Paramount\2017 Data\Summary\2017 Summary - Edit.xlsm"

Workbooks("2017 Summary - Edit.xlsm").Worksheets("Input P").Activate

Range("C18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this function from here on SO (Dont remember the post to give proper credit to unfortnuatley.

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Then in your Sub you call it using something like this:

```
Dim ret

ret = IsWorkBookOpen(Path to workbook here)

Select Case ret
    Case Is True:  code here
    Case Is False: code here
End Select
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm coming across stupid but does the function go inside the Sub or before the Sub? Thanks for your help

Comment: This function would go outside of the sub and no need to apologize we all still learn things thanks to SO.